# Problem with initialize react native application

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to create new app but upon running init I'm facing issue on first step - Resolving packages.

Command:
`npx react-native init doggo --verbose`

Error:

```
debug Installing template from react-native@latest
yarn init v1.22.19
warning The yes flag has been set. This will automatically answer yes to all questions, which may have security implications.
success Saved package.json
✨  Done in 0.03s.
yarn config v1.22.19
success Set "nodeLinker" to "node-modules".
✨  Done in 0.03s.
yarn add v1.22.19
info No lockfile found.
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
error Couldn't find package "react-native" on the "npm" registry.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
error Installing pods failed. This doesn't affect project initialization and you can safely proceed. 
However, you will need to install pods manually when running iOS, follow additional steps in "Run instructions for iOS" section.
```

As you can see, error says that react-native package doesn't exist but it is in fact

```
filip@MacBook-Pro-Filip-2 IdeaProjects % npm config get registry
https://registry.npmjs.org/
filip@MacBook-Pro-Filip-2 IdeaProjects % yarn config get registry
https://registry.yarnpkg.com
filip@MacBook-Pro-Filip-2 IdeaProjects % npx react-native -v
12.3.6
```

Comment: What's your OS? If it's macOS, What's your architecture type? M series?

Comment: Hi Fifis, did you find the solution? If not maybe I can help

Answer (score 1):

I'm noticing that your react-native version is: `12.3.6`
However, on the [npm registry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native), the latest version is: `0.73.6`

Pulled this from the react native documentation:

If you still have the old CLI installed try running:

```
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli @react-native-community/cli
```

as it may cause unexpected issues.

Then try running

```
npx react-native@latest init doggo --verbose
```

If the issue still persists, I would specify the react-native version

```
npx react-native@X.XX.X init doggo --version X.XX.X
```

With `npx react-native <command>`, the version of the CLI will be downloaded and executed at the time the command is run.